# How to get count of markers at visible region on map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Please help!!!
i have read - [How to get all visible markers on current zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906427/how-to-get-all-visible-markers-on-current-zoom-level) , but i have over than 2000 markers on map, and my app works very slowly.

Is there another solution ???

code -

```
public boolean isVisibleArea(final Marker marker) {
   final LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
   final VisibleRegion visibleRegion = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
   bld.include(visibleRegion.farLeft)
      .include(visibleRegion.farRight)
      .include(visibleRegion.nearLeft)
      .include(visibleRegion.nearRight);
   return bld.build().contains(marker.getPosition());
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it is really faster, but this code is definitely cleaner:

```
public boolean isVisibleOnMap(LatLng latLng) {
    VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
    return vr.latLngBounds.contains(latLng);
}
```