# List the Marker that is on Screen Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i want to create a List that display the Markers within the Zoom Range like this site http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/map/

I want to create the list using Jquery or is there a Built in function for google Maps v3 ??

Thanks

Comment: did you got solution to this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this answer:
[How to get all visible markers on current zoom level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7761311/2327005)

Using `LatLngBounds.contain()` you can determine if a LatLng is within certain bounds

Comment: Can this Create A List like the Given Link?

Comment: No, this will not create a list by itself. You should add your code to generate your html list below this line: `// code for showing your object, associated with markers[i]`