# Get Visible Markers in google_maps_flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Using [Google Maps for Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter) I've placed some markers on different places on the map. I have a separate RaisedButton on my Flutter app which I need to only be visible when one or more of those markers are currently visible on the map.

How can this be achieved? I've found a somewhat [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906427/how-to-get-all-visible-markers-on-current-zoom-level) for Google Maps API but I need this for google_maps_flutter on Flutter.

Answer (score 6):

`LatLngBounds` has specific method known as `contains()` which works along with `GoogleMapController`'s `getVisibleRegion()`.

*From the official docs:*

```dart
contains(LatLng point) → bool
Returns whether this rectangle contains the given LatLng.
```

#### Usage:

```dart
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

static final CameraPosition _positionCenter = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(40.730610, -73.935242),
    zoom: 3.5,
);

Future<LatLngBounds> _getVisibleRegion() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    final LatLngBounds bounds = await controller.getVisibleRegion();
    return bounds;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void checkMarkers() async {
        LatLngBounds bounds = await _getVisibleRegion();
        Set<Marker> markers = Set<Marker>.of(markers.values);

        markers.forEach((marker) {
            print('Position: ${ marker.position } - Contains: ${ bounds.contains(marker.position) }');
        });
    }

    return GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
        initialCameraPosition: _positionCenter,
        onCameraIdle: () {
            checkMarkers();
        },
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
            _controller.complete(controller);
            checkMarkers();
        },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`google_maps_flutter` is a developer preview at version 0.0.3.  Please hang in there a bit until more functionality is introduced.

Comment: Would you kindly let me know if there's an alternative method to achieve this? I'm open to changing the plugin as well.

Comment: Nothing is close yet.  Keep watching google_maps_flutter, as it is a project of the Flutter team.