# Api google maps list name marker

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I have a div with maps and another div for the list of pointer markers on the map. How to update the list with the name of the markers on the current map when zooming in on the map?
[image: go]

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answer is exactly what you need:
[answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906427/how-to-get-all-visible-markers-on-current-zoom-level#answer-63197923)

It has a link to a code pen that quite well seems to describe what you want.